# Jquery select tbody but not from nested tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to append data to a table, that gets selected using jquery.  The problem is, this table may have nested tables within it.  What happens is that when I append the data, not just the parent table's tbody gets appended but so too does all the children tables tbody.  Here is my code:

```
var template = window.app.getTemplate('myTemplate');
var image = {id: imageId, name: imageName, imageList: imageTypes, extension: ext, thumbNail: thumbNailPath};
$("#MyTable tbody:first").append(template(image));
```

Where myTemplate is set up like this:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
<tr>
</tr>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

and MyTable is set up like this:

```
<table id="MyTable" data-attr="images">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Like I said, when the append happens, if there is more than one table within tbody, all tbody's get appended to.  So, how do I select only the first?

thanks

Comment: you can use '>' operator to find the tbody as `$("#MyTable > tbody")`

Comment: `tbody:first` should prevent the append on all the tbody... Can you reproduce the problem? I can't..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery uses the CSS selectors to reach the element.

```
$("#MyTable > tbody:first")
```

> E > F Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

See more at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you update your jquery selector

```
$("#MyTable > tbody:first")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#MyTable > tbody").append(template(image));
```